# Need help to debug jQuery selector logic

Tags: jquery

I have a drop-down selector and need to load other parts of the form based on selection. I need to make sure that NO same options are selected. Here's my attempt to validate based on @Mike Ruhlin suggestion. It still does not work, but I feel like I'm quite close. Also, I noticed that my logic broke. By selecting one option all three below are showing the same now. Each selection should load only one selection imediately below.

What am I missing here?

Here's what I've got so far:

```
$('.mySelector').change(function(){

        var selectForm = '.' + $(this).val();           

        if (selectForm != '.selectOne') {
            // check for dupe selections
            var alreadyUsed = {};

            $("select").each(function(){

                var thisVal = $(this).val();

                if(alreadyUsed[thisVal]){
                    // found a dupe
                    alert('already used');
                }

                $('div').next('.fLoad').load('formParts.html ' + $selectForm );

            });
        }
});

<select class="mySelector">
   <option value="selectOne">Select one</option>
   <option value="o1">Car details</option>
   <option value="o2">Boat details</option>
   <option value="o3">Train details</option>
   <option value="o4">Bike details</option>
   <option value="o5">Sub details</option>
</select>

<div class='fLoad'> </div>

<select class="mySelector">
   <option value="selectOne">Select one</option>
   <option value="o1">Car details</option>
   <option value="o2">Boat details</option>
   <option value="o3">Train details</option>
   <option value="o4">Bike details</option>
   <option value="o5">Sub details</option>
</select>

<div class='fLoad'> </div>

<select class="mySelector">
   <option value="selectOne">Select one</option>
   <option value="o1">Car details</option>
   <option value="o2">Boat details</option>
   <option value="o3">Train details</option>
   <option value="o4">Bike details</option>
   <option value="o5">Sub details</option>
</select>

<div class='fLoad'> </div>
```

Comment: Aren't you missing a `<select>` around the second set of options?

Comment: Yes, good catch. Copy'n'paste... +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i wasn't sure what you were doing with this:

```
$('div').next('.fLoad').load('formParts.html ' + $selectForm );
```

I figured you can put it back in the right spot ;)

```
 $('.mySelector').change(function(index, elem){
    var filter = $(this).val();
    if(filter !="selectOne"){
        var size = $('.mySelector').not(this).not(function(index){
            return $(this).val() != filter;
        }).size();
      if(size > 0){
        alert("duplicates!");
     }

    }

});
```

Comment: @santa your original code would load your form in quite a few places, i would look at valera's post to load the $(this).next('div.fLoad')  logic as my solution has pulled you out of a .each() loop

Comment: Oh, I use a value from a selected option to fetch an element with the same class name from an external document. Your code is right ON! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your `$('div')` selector selects **all** divs on the page and looks for a .float class after them. I'm assuming you want to select only the div immediately after the current `<select>`.

You'll have to do something like `$(this).next('div.fLoad').load(url)`

Also, I'm not sure what you're trying to load with `'formParts.html ' + $selectForm`, since you'll have a url with a filename, a space, and a select value. If you want to pass the value as a parameter, it would have to be in this form: `formParts.html?paramName=paramValue`, but then html files don't process parameters. Although, that's a whole other issue. :)

Comment: I'm loading a part of a form from an external page. It works fine when I only have one select. When I add validation, that's where I'm having problems.